# $\frac{1}{\frac{5}{9}\bigr(1 + \frac{D}{3} - \frac{D^2}{3} \bigr)}(5x^2)$ to $\frac{5}{9}\bigr(1 + \frac{D}{3} - \frac{D^2}{3} \bigr)x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was following the steps from the book [*Ordinary Differential Equations*](https://books.google.com.gh/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations.html?id=iU4zDAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) (Lesson 25B page 274) to find a particular solution of

> $4y'' - 3y' + 9y = 5x^2, \quad (4D^2 -3D +9)y = 5x^2$

And theses were the steps

$ y_p = \frac{1}{9\bigr(1 + \frac{D}{3} - \frac{D^2}{3} \bigr)}(5x^2) $

$ y_p =  \frac{5}{9}\bigr(1 + \frac{D}{3} - \frac{D^2}{3} \bigr)x^2 $

**My problem is: I don't know how they had**

> $ y_p =  \frac{5}{9}\bigr(1 + \frac{D}{3} - \frac{D^2}{3} \bigr)x^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $$\dfrac 1 {1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=1+x+x^2+\dots$$
$$4y'' - 3y' + 9y = 5x^2, \quad (4D^2 -3D +9)y = 5x^2\implies y_p=\dfrac 5 {4D^2 -3D +9} (x^2).$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
y_p &= \frac{5}{{9}\bigr(1 - \frac{D}{3} + \frac{4D^2}{9} \bigr)}(x^2) =\frac 5 9 \frac{1}{\bigr(1 -( \frac{D}{3} - \frac{4D^2}{9}) \bigr)}(x^2)\\
&=\frac 5 9 \left(1 +\left( \frac{D}{3} - \frac{4D^2}{9}\right) +\left( \frac{D}{3} - \frac{4D^2}{9}\right) ^2+\dots\right)(x^2)\\
&=\frac 5 9 \left(1 +\left( \frac{D}{3} - \frac{4D^2}{9}\right) +\frac{D^2}{9} \right)(x^2)\\
&=\frac 5 9 \left(1 + \frac{D}{3} - \frac{D^2}{3} \right)(x^2).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please how do I do that. I am now learning

Comment: @EALehn is it more clear now ?

Comment: Thank you Robert ..@Robert Z

Comment: @EALehn we dont need the terms with exponent greater than 2. Because $D^3 x^2 =0$ These terms are zero. We only keep the terms $D,D^2$ In the Taylor serie.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you

Comment: @EALehn You're welcomed.